# How to use mongodump to export specified collections only

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodump

I checked the [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#std-option-mongodump.--collection) docs, and I found this:

```
--collection=<collection>, -c=<collection>
```

> Specifies a collection to backup. If you do not specify a collection, this option copies all collections in the specified database or instance to the dump files.

This specifies one specific collection. I want to export multiple collections, but not all. Is there a way to specify all collections that I want to export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify all the collections to export, but you can specify which collections not to export using `--excludeCollection`, like this:

`mongodump  --db=test --excludeCollection=users --excludeCollection=salaries`

It is listed on the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I just found that.